# SwiftUI: Dismiss all active sheet views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How to dismiss all active sheets within an app? I have 2 app modes

```
switch appMode {
  case .locked:
    lockedView
  case .unlocked:
    contentView
}
```

When app mode change from one state to another and in current state there is some sheet view this sheet doesn't dissapear. Is there some SwiftUI solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this line to dismissing all the presented sheets.

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

iOS 15

'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15

```
let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .filter {$0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
        .map {$0 as? UIWindowScene }
        .compactMap { $0 }
        .first?.windows
        .filter({ $0.isKeyWindow }).first?.rootViewController
    
    rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true) {
        // TODO: something
    }
```

Comment: Can't event imagine that In 2023 this is still working solution for swiftui. I still can't dismiss presented sheet from its children.

Comment: iOS 15 introduced [UIWindowScene.keyWindow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3750932-keywindow) property